# Using __VA_ARGS for printf

Tags: c, printf, c-preprocessor

I am trying to write `#define` for `ASSERT()` using `__VA_ARGS`.
(This code is for an embedded processor which doesn't support all libc functions).

My source code is like this:

```
ASSERT(msg == NULL)
```

`ASSERT` in header file:

```
#define ASSERT(...) if(__VA_ARGS__) { printf("[ASSERT ERROR]" __VA_ARGS__ "\n"); }
```

The preprocessor output is like this, which results compilation error.

```
if(msg == NULL) { printf("[ASSERT ERROR]" msg == NULL "\n"); }
```

How do I fix the `#define` to get rid of compilation errors while keeping the code logically correct?

Comment: What's the point of the macro?

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason for this to be a variadic macro, at least not with telling us more information about what exactly you're trying to do.  A simple one-argument macro using the stringizing operator `#` will do the trick nicely:

```
#define ASSERT(x) if(x); else printf("[ASSERT ERROR] " #x "\n")
```

Also note that I omitted the semicolon at the end and wrote it as `if(x); else` instead of `if(!(x))`, so that all of the following code fragments compile correctly as you'd expect, or produce a compiler error as you'd expect:

```
// #1 - this must be an error, no semicolon
ASSERT(x)

// #2 - this must also be an error
ASSERT(x)
else
    /*stuff*/ ;

// #3 - the else must go with the first if, not the inner if inside the macro
// expansion
if (x)
    ASSERT(y);
else
    /*stuff*/ ;
```

Your original macro definition fails test #3 above.

Comment: +1, but some compilers will still issue bogus `else` warnings on `if (to) ASSERT(x);`, unfortunately. For such cases encapsulating in the good old `do { .. } while(false)` still rules. And also there is no reason *not* to do the macro with `__VA_ARGS__`. somebody might want to pass a comma expression to it :)

Comment: @Jens: True, some compilers can be picky.  One reason to avoid `__VA_ARGS__` if it's not necessary is that it's a C99 feature, so you can't use it with C89 compilers that don't support it as an extension.  If you really wanted to pass a comma expression, you could add an extra set of parentheses to the non-variadic macro, e.g. `ASSERT((foo, bar))`.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield Thanks for the suggestions. In my code i have `ASSERT(x)` and my define is `#define ASSERT(x) if(x){ } else { printf("[ASSERT BUG]" #x "\n");` and it compiles successfully.

Comment: @SudharsanSeshadri: You must remove the braces and the semicolon around the call to `printf` in that macro, otherwise **it can result in code compiling successfully but silently doing the wrong thing** -- precisely case #3 in my example above.  Macros are tricky to get right (hence why [some people think they're evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/use-evil-things-sometimes.html)).